Switching from .first() to .collect{} on a Flow stopped data appearing on screen
I did a viewmodel with Flow and Room that connected my variables on the UiState with Room using .first() as the Codelabs showed me. I noticed that using .first() is not a good idea because when I inserted something in the database, the screen didn't get refreshed automatically showing the new value.
So I learned that using collect{} is the correct approach to continuously update the uistate variables automatically. After changing it now my screen is not showing any data and I can't discover why. How can I find the issue? I'm adding the viewmodel here.
You can see the old code commented. I mean the code with .first() that worked, but without updating automatically. The commented code is followed by the new code with collect{} that didn't work at all.
data class UiState(
    val searchResult: List<Airport> = listOf(),
    val favorites: List<Favorite> = listOf(),
    val selectedAirport: Airport? = null,
    val flightsForSelectedAirport: List<Airport> = listOf()
)

class FlightsScreenViewModel(
    private val flightRepository: FlightsRepository,
    private val userPreferencesRepository: UserPreferencesRepository
) : ViewModel() {
    var uiState by mutableStateOf(UiState())
        private set

    var searchText by mutableStateOf("")
        private set

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
//          searchText = userPreferencesRepository.searchText.first()
            userPreferencesRepository.searchText.collect{ searchText = it }
            updateSearchResults()
        }
    }

    private suspend fun updateSearchResults() {
//        val searchResult = if (searchText != "")
//            flightRepository.getAirportsByIatOrName(searchText).filterNotNull().first()
//        else
//            emptyList()
//
//        val favorites = flightRepository.getFavorites().filterNotNull().first()
//
//        uiState = uiState.copy(
//            searchResult = searchResult,
//            favorites = favorites
//        )

        if (searchText != "") {
            flightRepository.getAirportsByIatOrName(searchText).filterNotNull().collect{ uiState = uiState.copy(searchResult = it) }
        } else {
            uiState = uiState.copy(favorites = emptyList())
        }

        flightRepository.getFavorites().filterNotNull().collect{ uiState = uiState.copy(favorites = it) }
    }

    fun updateSearchText(searchText: String) {
        this.searchText = searchText
        viewModelScope.launch {
            userPreferencesRepository.saveSearchTextPreference(searchText)
            updateSearchResults()
        }
    }

    fun selectAirport(airport: Airport?) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
//            val flightsForSelectedAirport = if (airport == null) {
//                emptyList()
//            } else {
//                flightRepository.getAllDifferentAirports(airport.id).first()
//            }
//
//            uiState = uiState.copy(
//                selectedAirport = airport,
//                flightsForSelectedAirport = flightsForSelectedAirport
//            )

            if (airport != null) {
                flightRepository.getAllDifferentAirports(airport.id).collect{ uiState = uiState.copy(flightsForSelectedAirport = it) }
            } else {
                uiState = uiState.copy(flightsForSelectedAirport = emptyList())
            }

            uiState = uiState.copy(selectedAirport = airport)
        }
    }

    fun insertFavorite(depart: String, arrive: String) {
        if (!uiState.favorites.checkIfFavoriteExists(depart, arrive)) {
            val favorite = Favorite(departureCode = depart, destinationCode = arrive)
            viewModelScope.launch {
                flightRepository.insertFavorite(favorite)
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        val factory : ViewModelProvider.Factory = viewModelFactory {
            initializer {
                FlightsScreenViewModel(
                    FlightSearchApplication().container.flightRepository,
                    FlightSearchApplication().container.userPreferencesRepository
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

fun List<Favorite>.checkIfFavoriteExists(depart: String, arrive: String): Boolean{
    for (favorite in this){
        if (favorite.departureCode == depart && favorite.destinationCode == arrive)
            return true
    }
    return false
}

This is the code that should show the content in the screen, but is not showing nothing after updating from .first() to .collect{}
LazyColumn(
    modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp)
) {
    items(uiState.searchResult) { airport ->
        AirportDetail(airport, onAirportSelected)
    }
}
uiState.selectedAirport?.let {
    FlightsForAirport(
        airport = uiState.selectedAirport,
        arrivals = uiState.flightsForSelectedAirport,
        favorites = uiState.favorites,
        onFavoriteSelected = onFavoriteSelected
    )
}


The code lab is outdated. This is how it should be done instead:

Do not use MutableState in the view model, use a private MutableStateFlow instead.
Only transform flows in the view model, do not collect them.
Instead of a MutableState expose the resulting transformed flows as a StateFlow.

This is how your view model should look like instead:
class FlightsScreenViewModel(
    private val flightRepository: FlightsRepository,
    private val userPreferencesRepository: UserPreferencesRepository,
) : ViewModel() {
    private val searchResult: Flow<List<Airport>> =
        userPreferencesRepository.searchText.flatMapLatest {
            if (it.isEmpty()) flowOf(emptyList())
            else flightRepository.getAirportsByIatOrName(it).filterNotNull()
        }

    private val favorites: Flow<List<Favorite>> =
        flightRepository.getFavorites().filterNotNull()

    private val selectedAirport = MutableStateFlow<Airport?>(null)
    private val flightsForSelectedAirport: Flow<List<Airport>> =
        selectedAirport.flatMapLatest {
            if (it == null) flowOf(emptyList())
            else flightRepository.getAllDifferentAirports(it.id)
        }

    val uiState: StateFlow<UiState> = combine(
        searchResult,
        favorites,
        selectedAirport,
        flightsForSelectedAirport,
        ::UiState,
    ).stateIn(
        scope = viewModelScope,
        started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5_000),
        initialValue = UiState(),
    )

    fun updateSearchText(searchText: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            userPreferencesRepository.saveSearchTextPreference(searchText)
        }
    }

    fun selectAirport(airport: Airport?) {
        selectedAirport.value = airport
    }

    fun insertFavorite(depart: String, arrive: String) {
        val favorite = Favorite(departureCode = depart, destinationCode = arrive)
        viewModelScope.launch {
            flightRepository.insertFavorite(favorite)
        }
    }

    companion object { /* ... */ }
}

The flows are never collected, they are just transformed. The new transformed searchResult flow, for example, is created by using the userPreferencesRepository.searchText flow and mapping it to the flightRepository.getAirportsByIatOrName flow.
The new flightsForSelectedAirport flow on the other hand is based on a new MutableStateFlow<Airport?> that is used to store the currently selected airport. It can be used similar to a MutableState(*) in that its value property can be directly set as seen in the function fun selectAirport(). It is still a flow, though, so it can be transformed into a Flow<List<Airport>> here.
Now that all values that are needed to create a UiState are present in flows, these flows can be combined into a single Flow. That flow is then converted to a StateFlow (related to MutableStateFlow, not related to Compose State) and publicly exposed.
Any consumer of the view model can now collect that flow to get a UiState that will always be up to date. Use this in your composable:
val uiState by viewModel.uiState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

This is the bridge between the Kotlin world of Flows and the Compose world of States. It converts the StateFlow into a Compose State object. By using the by delegation uiState is actually of type UiState and the rest of your code will work the same as it previousy did.
You need the gradle dependency androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-compose for that.

Final thoughts:

You apply filterNotNull() to the getAirportsByIatOrName and getFavorites flows. It implies that the flows can not only contain a List, they can also contain null. That doesn't seem right, they should contain an emptyList() instead of null. Then you should remove filterNotNull().

I removed the checkIfFavoriteExists from insertFavorite. That should be done in the repository instead. The consistency of the data should not rely on what the view model does, that's the repository's reponsibility (or even that of the data source if you have that separated). Ideally that would be done before the data is even wrapped into a flow. It all depends on how this is actually implemented.
The function can also be streamlined a bit:
fun List<Favorite>.checkIfFavoriteExists(
    depart: String,
    arrive: String,
): Boolean = any {
    it.departureCode == depart && it.destinationCode == arrive
}


Instead of writing an explicit view model factory you can automate it by using a dependency injection framework like Hilt.



(*): Although MutableStateFlow and MutableState have similar names they are completely different types that are entirely unrelated. The former is part of Kotlin's standard lib where the latter is part of the Compose framework. They share some semantics as they both store an observable value that can be accessed by the value property, but that's all.

Hi @Leviathan , thank you for your answer, but I must say that it's very advanced for me. I consider your answer super complex. Can't understand it in fact. I can't believe there isn't a simpler and understandable way that is simply human readable to store some simple values of the current state of the UI. On the other hand I can't even make your code work. I think maybe it's because you removed the searchText mutablestate variable and it's necessary because it's connected to a TextField, which must work with a mutablestate variable and not directly with the repo. Also you removed init block.

also I need to get a uiState object with normal variables not a flow with flows inside, because it is necessary to paint these values on the composables, and your code don't have that too.

I'm sorry to hear that. I guess there's just a little bit missing for you to wrap your head around, you seem to already have a good grasp of a lot of the essential concepts needed for this approach (like flows). This code is actually significantly less complex compared to what you had before: There are just some static flow transformations as part of the view model's properties and simple set functions. I also find the code easier to read because all components are better encapsualted. The view model's internal variables are much less intertwined now.

But let me try to address the issues you raised, hopefully that makes it more clear.
1.) A TextField's value shouldn't be stored in the view model. Store it in your composables by either using a mutableStateOf<String> or rememberTextFieldState (with the latter being the somewhat more complex but future-proof way to go). Independent of that you can decide to also persist the value as you do with your repo's saveSearchTextPreference.

2.) I removed the init block because it isn't necessary anymore since the flows are no longer collected in the view model.
3.) You do get a "uiState object with normal variables". The type of val uiState by viewModel.uiState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle() is the simple data class UiState. At no point there is a "flow with flows inside" anywhere in the code. -- Actually, points 2.) and 3.) shouldn't even bother you because it will just work. The more relevant question would be what actually prevents you from running the code. Is there anything concrete I can assist with?

thank you very much, after 2 days of learning flow I think now I'm able to understand your code and make it work.

There is one thing I still not understand, why you must pass ::UiState as last parameter to uiState stateflow?

maybe can you help also with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78615077/how-to-query-a-room-db-from-a-composable-to-get-item-details

The last parameter to combine is the transformation function that creates the content of the combined flow. ::UiState is a simplified syntax to create a UiState object from the flows' content. Click on it and press Alt+Enter, then select "Convert reference to lambda" to see its full form. It is much more verbose, but maybe that helps you better understand what actually happens here.

The reason switching to collect stopped it from updating is that collect() is a function that doesn’t return to its caller until the entire flow has been consumed. A flow from Room is infinite (because it’s always waiting to see if another change will happen to the database so it can emit again), so a call to collect on a flow from Room will never return. Therefore, your updateSearchResults() line is unreachable code.
Actually, you’ll find that most applications of Flows are for infinite flows because they tend to represent a continuous stream of data, monitoring something for changes. Also, all SharedFlows and StateFlows are infinite (never finish without being cancelled) by definition.
If you need to call collect, you need to rearrange the order of calls in your coroutine so there are no calls after the collect() call, either my moving that call into the collect lambda, if appropriate, or by launching multiple parallel coroutines. However, as stated in Leviathan’s answer, typically you do not collect Flows in a ViewModel, especially if you’re using Compose.
