How to query a Room db from a composable to get item details
Having an application with Room and Compose, I'm on a composable that needs to retrieve data from the database for painting it. It is a list of favorite flights, and favorite only haves the IDs (iata) of the departure and destination airports. My composable haves the favorite but needs to do selects from airport table to recover all the data for each airport and be able to paint it. Is a list, so it need to do it for a lot of items.
Which is the correct approach? I thought was creating a function on the viewmodel that returns the result of the query but then I noticed that this whould return a Flow and not a object instance, also, the composable doesn't have the viewmodel, so I can't call functions of the viewmodel. Which is the best way to solve this?
The database entities:
@Entity
data class Airport(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "iata_code")
    val iataCode: String,
    val name: String,
    val passengers: Int
)

@Entity
data class Favorite(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "departure_code")
    val departureCode: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "destination_code")
    val destinationCode: String
)

The composable:
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp)
    ) {
        items(uiState.favorites) { favorite ->
            //TODO here i need to get two airports using the ids (iata), so I need to query room, once I have them, I can use them to paint the details of both airports of the favorite flight.
        }
    }

The viewmodel function to recover the airport by iata:
fun getAirportByIata(iata: String): Flow<Airport> {
        return flightRepository.getAirport(iata)
    }


You can convert your Airport's data into StateFlow in your ViewModel. Then calling StateFlow from ViewModel and convert it into State in your Composable.

Please have a look at the documentation about Room Relationships.
Instead of first retrieving the favorites, and then in a second database operation fetching the airports belonging to them, you can create a new data class like FavoritesAndAirports and let Room automatically join the two tables for you. Then you end up having all data needed already at one place:
items(uiState.favoritesAndAirports) { favoriteAndAirports ->
    // access favorites with their airports
}

In your case, you could model the two airports belonging to one favorite by using two one-to-one relationships. Create a data class like this:
data class FavoriteAndAirports(
    @Embedded val favorite: Favorite,
    
    @Relation(
         parentColumn = "departure_code",
         entityColumn = "iata_code"
    )
    val departureAirport: Airport
    
    @Relation(
         parentColumn = "destination_code",
         entityColumn = "iata_code"
    )
    val destinationAirport: Airport
)

I am assuming here that departure_code and destination_code are pointing towards the iata_code of the Airport entity.
Then, you can access it in your DAO similar to this:
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM Favorite")
fun getFavorites(): Flow<List<FavoriteAndAirports>>

Room will now load all Favorites, get the two Airports for each Favorite, and will put all the data into the FavoriteAndAirports instances. This Flow you then can access from your ViewModel:
class FlightsVM(
    private val flightRepository: FlightRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    val favorites = flightRepository
        .getFavorites()
        .stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.Lazily, emptyList())

}

Finally, consume it in your Composable:
@Composable
fun FavoritesComposable(flightViewModel: FlightVM = viewModel()) {
    val favorites = flightViewModel.favorites.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

    LazyColumn(
        //...
    )
}

I hope this is enough to get you started, otherwise please take a deeper look at the documentation I linked, there is good information provided there.

Hi, thanks, it seems to be a bit complex for me. What do you think about creating a flow with a list of a new data class containing the two airports of each favorite, all this on the viewmodel? is the same work under the hood? everytime that favorites is changed (for example inserting a new one), will a all the work of generating this list be done even without displaying this composable with the favorites? Is the same issue with your solution?

I think you should not manually assemble the Favorites with the Airports. With the approach described in my answer, Room will do everything for you.  It will fetch the airport data for each Favorite itself. I have used this approach several times without any performance problems. As also displayed in the documentation, this is the recommended way to implement it.

well finally I understand your solution and I'll accepting it, assuming that it's better than generating a flow that manually do the job, thank you
