How to pass a function that returns an object as a parameter to a composable?
I need a composable that needs to call a function from the viewmodel, and that function returns an instance of Airport object.
I did this:
@Composable
fun FlightsScreen(getAirportDetails: (String)-> Airport

Inside of the composable I use the parameter function as this:
                val depart = getAirportDetails(favorite.departureCode)
                val arrival = getAirportDetails(favorite.destinationCode)

                FlightDetail(
                    airport = depart,
                    arrival = arrival,
                    isFavorite = true,
                    onFavoriteSelected = onFavoriteSelected
                )

and In the upper composable I pass that function as this:
FlightsScreen(
            getAirportDetails = {
                viewModel.getAirportByIata(it).collectAsStateWithLifecycle(initialValue = Airport(0,"","",0)).value
            },

As you can see, in the lower composable I call the function passing the id of the airport and in the upper composable I use that function using that id and passing it to get the airport, and return it. In the lower composable I get the returner airport.
The problem is that I'm getting this error on the lower composable for that parameter:
@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function

How to achieve this correctly and why it forces me to add @Composable to a parameter function that is not a composable? I'm confussed.

Please have a look at the documentation of collectAsStateWithLifecycle:
@Composable <br>
fun <T : Any?> StateFlow<T>.collectAsStateWithLifecycle(
    lifecycle: Lifecycle,
    minActiveState: Lifecycle.State = Lifecycle.State.STARTED,
    context: CoroutineContext = EmptyCoroutineContext
): State<T>

As you can see, it is annotated as being a @Composable. Thus you can only call it from within another @Composable function, which (String)-> Airport is not.
Besides that, this way of using collectAsStateWithLifecycle will never work
viewModel.getAirportByIata(it).collectAsStateWithLifecycle(initialValue = Airport(0,"","",0)).value

because you will only read the first .value out of the Flow. If you want it to emit new values properly, you generally should use it like this:
@Composable
fun MyComposable(viewModel: MyViewModel = viewModel()) {
    val currentValue by viewModel.someFlow.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

    Text(text = currentValue.someProperty)
}

However, as others pointed out, a Flow might not be suitable in your use case.

then, how can I get the items I need on that composable? I explained the issue here opening a different question to get this working without this method:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78615077/how-to-query-a-room-db-from-a-composable-to-get-item-details

I will take a look.

the provided code is not sufficient to predict the error from the context,so i'm providing an answer based on my assumption:
if:
The function FlightsScreen doesn't contain any composables or compose code as per the provided data so it shouldn't need a @composable annotation, try removing it,
else if:
The function passed into the getAirportDetails is a compose function u have to change the return type
check this stack overflow question you may get some idea based on this
else provide the code such as the view model the whole composables and non composable funcs involved in the process.

It’s not the right approach. Even if you could get this working, it would cause this Composable to be unstable, so it would be recomposing all the time even when the relevant data it displays was not changing.
You either need to make the parameter the airport or the ViewModel that can fetch the airport. Then you can collect as state inside this Composable, rather than in its property initializer.

you mean passing the viewmodel as a parameter on the composable?

Yes, you can pass it in as a parameter. Putting it as a parameter with default value of = viewModel() is the recommended approach in the Android documentation. That leaves it open for unit testing while in your application code you don’t have to think about it. See here: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/compose/libraries#viewmodel But if this Composable is not the top level of a screen, you should be using the other approach…only pass the airport as a parameter.

And, yes, this leads to your intermediately nested composables having a lot of parameters that the top level Composable has to extract from the ViewModel and pass along, leading to lots of boilerplate. It’s one of the ugly parts of Compose.
